# Find certain strings from an array

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I am trying to execute a find function on a payload.

Suppose I have :

```
["john","abe","john","doe","peter"]
```

The expected output is

```
[
"john",
"john",
"peter"
]
```

I tried to do

```
["john","abe","john","doe","peter"] find "john" or "peter"
```

but it doesn't work.

I don't know how to do it.

Comment: You should always add the expected output to this kind of question.

Comment: I edited it to show the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the filter() function to find items that comply with a condition. As the condition you can have another array of the elements that you are interested and test if the current element is contained in the interested array. Since there is no clear expectation for the output, I choose to return all matching elements. You may want to return something different.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var choices=["john","peter"]
---
["john","abe","john","doe","peter"] filter ( choices contains $ )
```

Output:

```json
[
  "john",
  "john",
  "peter"
]
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply aled :) this was exactly what I needed

Answer (score 1):

match can find the required char matches:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var ip = ['john','abe','john','doe','peter']
var toFind = /john|peter/
---
flatten(ip map ($ match toFind))
```

Output:

```
[
  "john",
  "john",
  "peter"
]
```